# How can I use a phonetic method to type Bulgarian on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 on my laptop. My operating system was installed already on my computer and the only thing I needed to do was set my registration and set my region and language.

Having done that, when I came to set a keyboard language I did not see a Bulgarian phonetic keyboard option.

How can I type in Bulgarian using a phonetic method on 18.10?

Comment: There are both a traditional and a new phonetic option available. Possibly you missed that you need to click the _Bulgarian_ option to see the other variants in the next menu.

Answer (score 2):

To change the language settings on Ubuntu 18.10 (18.04) open the user's by click on the the upper right corner and click on the settings button. Then choice *Region & Language* from the left side of the Settings application.

[image]

By click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button (1), you can add a new *Input source*. According to the question, probably you need *Bulgarian (traditional phonetic)*. When there is more than one *Input source* the language switcher will appear in the toolbar (2). You need to log-off and log-in (or reboot the system) to apply the new *Input source*.

By the button <kbd>Options</kbd> (3) you can change the behavior of the language switcher when you switch the windows. Also there is an instructions how to change the keyboard shortcut, which by default is <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

[image]

If you click on the button <kbd>Manage Installed Languages</kbd> (4), initially you will be asked to install an additional common language support tools and then you will be able to add extended system support for Bulgarian. For example the [Bulgarian spell check in LibreOffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUdCB.png) will be available.

By the option *Languages* (5) you can switch the system language. In this case I would [keep the original names names of the user's folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVbvS.png). By option *Formats* (6) you can change the Date/Time/etc. display format.